# Enthought Canopy v1.41, and thinkpython.com/code/swampy causes crash

Tags: python, osx-mavericks, enthought, canopy, swampy

Trying to learn python. Chapter 4 of Think Python by Allen Downey requires you to download package from [thinkpython.com/swampy](http://thinkpython.com/swampy).  Had trouble implementing the directions on the website, so I copied Swampy to it's own directory.

```
from swampy.TurtleWorld import *
world=TurtleWorld()
```

works in the interactive environment. But when I write a script and attempt to run it, python crashes and I need to re-start the kernel.  Other posts on this topic suggest modifying the user path, setting Canopy as the default python environment.  I'm sharing a computer (Mac Mavericks  10.9.5) and would like to to the exercises in the book w/o changing anything that will effect the other users of this computer.  I'm afraid that if I change the default python setting I'll mess it up for other users.

Q: How do I import and run on my own mac user account w/o changing defaults of other users?

Answer (score 0):

This problem and solution is described on the Enthought support knowledge base at https://support.enthought.com/entries/21793229-Using-Tkinter-Turtle-or-Pyglet-in-Canopy-s-IPython-panel.

As a side note, you don't need to change your default Python at all. If you do want to run Canopy Python in Terminal, which can indeed be useful although it is not necessary to solve your problem, just go to the Canopy Tools menu and open a Canopy Terminal.